# Using interpolation as a string in different function call

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
componentDidMount() {

    let env = clientConfiguration['Environment'];
    let x = `communitiesApi.${env}`;

    fetch(clientConfiguration[x])
        .then((response) => {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(data => {
            let communitiesFromApi = data.map(community => { return { value: community, display: community } })
            this.setState({ communities: [{ value: '', display: '(Select your favourite community)' }].concat(communitiesFromApi) });
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
}
```

I am trying to use the result x value as a string in the `clientConfiguration[x]` call, but it's not happening, x is coming as `"communitiesApi.local"`, which is correct, but when I am trying to use this as a string in the `clientConfiguration["communitiesApi.local"]`, it gives me some api url, but when I am using `clientConfiguration[x]`, it is not returning the correct value.

Comment: What exactly does `clientConfiguration` look like?

Answer (score 0):

This shouldn't be an answer, but I made this example just so you can see that the problem isn't with string interpolation, but probably some syntax error that depends on how `clientConfiguration` looks like.

```js
let a = {
  "hello.world": 123
}

let w = "world"

let s = `hello.${w}`

console.log(a[s])
```

As you can see, you can use interpolation string to access a property of an object.

And an example exactly as your case would be

```js
let clientConfiguration = {
  "communitiesApi.local": "some api local"
}

let env = "local"

let x = `communitiesApi.${env}`

console.log(clientConfiguration[x])
```

Comment: If that's the case then this following line felting me the correct result why? fetch(clientConfiguration['communitiesApi.local'])
            .then((response) => {
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(data => {
                let communitiesFromApi = data.map(community => { return { value: community, display: community } })
                this.setState({ communities: [{ value: '', display: 'Select a Community...' }].concat(communitiesFromApi) });
            }).catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            });

Comment: @Abdul Please show what you see in `console.log(clientConfiguration)`

Comment: @Abdul You say `is not printing the correct value` but you don't say what is the printed value or that should be the printed value. Please be more clear on what you have and what you expect

Comment: It seems something is missing. For some reason this is not printing the correct value: console.log(clientConfiguration[x]), any idea reason could be buddy?

Comment: Hi, here is what it shows in the console.log(clientConfiguration): default:
Environment: "local"
communitiesApi.local: "https://localhost:44352/api/communities"
communitiesApi.prod: ""
communitiesApi.test: ""
filesApi.local: "https://localhost:44352/api/communities"
filesApi.prod: ""
filesApi.test: ""